# Swap values between columns, by descending order in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
Name  Out1 Out2 Out3
Dave  2    3    3
Pete  3    3    4
John  2    NA   NA
```

I need to sort the 3 'Out' columns by descending order
So I would end up with:

```
Name  Out1 Out2 Out3
Dave  3    3    2
Pete  4    3    3
John  2    NA   NA
```

I have NAs which are fine, as long as if there's a value in that row, it's pushed to 'Out1'

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `apply` and `sort` the values in row-wise fashion in descending order. By default `sort` removes `NA` values so we add `na.last = TRUE` to keep `NA`s at the last.

```
df[-1] <- t(apply(df[-1], 1, sort, decreasing = TRUE, na.last = TRUE))

df
#  Name Out1 Out2 Out3
#1 Dave    3    3    2
#2 Pete    4    3    3
#3 John    2   NA   NA
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Name = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Dave", 
"John", "Pete"), class = "factor"), Out1 = c(2L, 3L, 2L), Out2 = c(3L, 
3L, NA), Out3 = c(3L, 4L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in `tidyverse` with `pivot_longer/pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -Name) %>% 
   group_by(Name) %>% 
   mutate(value = value[order(-value)]) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   Name [3]
#  Name   Out1  Out2  Out3
#  <fct> <int> <int> <int>
#1 Dave      3     3     2
#2 Pete      4     3     3
#3 John      2    NA    NA
```

---

Or another option is `pmap`

```
library(purrr)
df %>%
    select(-Name) %>%
    pmap(~ c(...) %>% 
             sort.int(decreasing = TRUE, na.last = TRUE) %>% 
             set_names(names(df)[-1]) %>% 
             as.list) %>% 
    tibble(Name = df$Name, Out = .) %>% 
    unnest_wider(Out)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  Name   Out1  Out2  Out3
#  <fct> <int> <int> <int>
#1 Dave      3     3     2
#2 Pete      4     3     3
#3 John      2    NA    NA
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Name = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Dave", 
"John", "Pete"), class = "factor"), Out1 = c(2L, 3L, 2L), Out2 = c(3L, 
3L, NA), Out3 = c(3L, 4L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
3L))
```